# PayPal Pay Now Button - Email Link

Tags: paypal

I have browsed this forum and been through the PayPal documentation but I am confused. I know what I need but cannot work-out how to specify it for my coder.

We have a .Net application that runs on our internal network. We use this application to create customer quotations. These quotations are emailed to our customers. I simply want the application to be create a link that I can send to the customer such then when it is opened it takes them straight into Paypal and allows then to make a payment for the quotation. Or maybe the link is embedded into the body of the quotation that I send. Either would be fine.

I know of programs that do this (Sage Line50 does it with Sagepay rather than PayPal) but I cannot get my head around the process. Most of my research is talking about taking payments from an external website but trawling through the PayPal documentation it looks like it should be possible. But I cannot figure out whether I need Smart Buttons or PayPal Me. The key thing is that I don't want to force customers to have a PayPal account so guest access must be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Smart Payment Buttons would be ideal, and offer the best payment experience to your customers. However, they require your own server on which to host some HTML/JS for them. They do *not* offer a link that can take the customer directly from an email to a PayPal checkout.

I recommend using Smart Payment Buttons, if you are able to host one. The flow is:

Email -> page on your server with Smart Button -> PayPal payment.

> The key thing is that I dont want to force customers to have a PayPal account so guest access must be an option.

PayPal.me does not meet that requirement

If your requirement is truly a link that proceeds directly:

Email -> PayPal.com checkout for payment  (no webserver of yours) ... well, there two solutions for this.

One is to use PayPal invoicing, which can be emailed directly by PayPal, or can be a link which you share yourself (via your own email). A PayPal invoice can be created manually via: https://www.paypal.com/invoice/create .  Or programmatically via the invoicing API (see developer.paypal.com)

The second way, which may work fine but is a very old web 1.0 way of doing things, is to start by going to http://www.paypal.com/buttons and create a Buy Now button for an item named "Placeholder", amount "777.88".  Expand the section "Step 2", and uncheck the option to Save the button at PayPal. Do not change any of the customization options, particularly ones that add menus or input fields.

Once you have generated the code, click the option above it to remove code protection, and then switch to the E-mail tab.

This will give you a plain HTML link with a description and amount that can be set dynamically by your developer when sending your own email. Additional useful variables, such as `invoice` (for an invoice number that is unique for what is being paid for, and can't be accidentally paid twice) [are documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/).

Again, Smart Payment Buttons should be preferred if you have a web server to act as an intermediary. [Here is a skeleton demo of the experience](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client).

Comment: Thanks for the help on this which makes so much sense. Can you point me in the direction of something that explains to me the hosting of Smart Buttons? I have a webserver which hosts my ecommerce website, so could I use that and what would I need to create?

Comment: Talk to your developer about that. If they are sending custom emails, they may be doing so from somewhere that can host a smart button.  At a minimum, it just needs to be a publicly accessible web server that can host an HTML file with javascript in it.